# Nginx proxy_pass with Node and SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx

I have managed to setup HTTPS using Nginx on a Node server at `localhost:4000` by placing the cert and key paths in the Nginx conf file, however, I would also like to understand how to embed the ssl certificate inside the node index.js file and just pass the proxy'd address to the  `localhost:4000` with the certs inside the application rather than the `nginx.conf` file.

This nginx.conf file will work correctly with https/ssl once node isn't being served as ssl.

```
server {
  listen 4500 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

However, if I comment out the following `nginx.conf`

```
#    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ballers.ie/fullchain.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.ballers.ie/privkey.pem;
```

And then add the certs to my node server as follows, it tells me that the site can't be reached.

```
// ...
// dependencies & config
// ...

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com.privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com.cert.pem', 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com.chain.pem', 'utf8');

const credentials = {
  key: privateKey,
  cert: certificate,
  ca,
};

const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send('I am a HTTPS endpoint !');
});

httpsServer.listen(4000);
```

I have also tried changing `proxy_pass` to `proxy_pass https://localhost:4000;`

I'd be very interested to understand how to make this work, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: For nginx to pass-through TLS to/from the backend you need to use `stream` (i.e. TCP aka L4, layer 4) mode. I'm sure I've seen this before but the closest I can find is https://serverfault.com/questions/835984/nginx-reverse-proxy-passthrough-of-client-tls-certificate (which focusses on client side but actually applies to backend as well). In this mode nginx isn't really doing anything for you and you might as well have the incoming connections be accepted directly by nodejs.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Yes, with further reading and research it appears that proxy pass through doesn't seem to work easily, so I would be better off keeping the certs with the nginx instance. Interesting to know it is possible all the same.